# Unit testing ValidationRules

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, validation, xaml

I have written a small library of ValidationRules and want to make sure it passes a good number of comprehensive tests. I want to unit test them but I am not exactly sure how to unit test a validation rule. I would think it is similar to testing any other method but there are a few things I am not sure on.

For example, a few of my validation rules have properties that I use to pass parameters through the XAML. I don't want to come up with a hack to do this since many people will be adding validators and building upon my unit testing suite.

`<utils:RestrictInputTypeValidator Restriction="IntegersOnly" ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"/>` In this example, "Restriction" is a property of the Validation Rule "RestrictInputTypeValidator."

I have not found any good resources on unit testing validation and would love to look at some examples of the best practices in doing it.

Comment: What's the difference between unit testing this and any other class?

Comment: The way the methods are triggered through binding and not simply "called." The way you pass arguments in the form of a property, etc. I am not saying that it couldn't be done in a hacky way the same way you would test any other class. My issue is that it is different enough for me to believe that there are best practices for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every validation you use in XAML derives from the `ValidationRule` class which has the following `Validate` overload:

```
ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
```

You can simply call this method in your unit test and examine the returned `ValidationResult` object, which contains an `IsValid` property that indicates whether the passed value is valid.

As this is a class like any other, you can simply pass the required properties in your unit test as usual:

```
var validator = new RestrictInputTypeValidator()
validator.Restriction = MyRestrictionEnum.IntegersOnly;

// Here for example our input is invalid.
var result = validator.Validate("My Input", MyCulture);
Assert.IsFalse(result.IsValid);
```

Comment: What about the properties that are essentially used as parameters?